# MySQL Query Select from table count total and used, calculate remaining

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have two tables :

```
-- **phones**

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phones` (
`phone_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`phone_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`phone_mac` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`office_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`did_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`virtual_extension_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`phone_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `phone_mac` (`phone_mac`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=67 ;

INSERT INTO `phones` (`phone_id`, `phone_type_id`, `phone_mac`, `office_id`, `did_id`, `virtual_extension_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, '0004f22ccccc', 5, NULL, NULL),
(63, 1, '0004f22bbbbb', 9, 33, NULL),
(64, 20, '0004f22aaaaa', 6, NULL, 6600),
(65, 2, '000033434333', 9, NULL, NULL),
(66, 20, '21232da32434', 6, NULL, NULL);

--  **phone_types**

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phone_types` (
  `phone_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `phone_type_manufacturer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone_type_model` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`phone_type_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `phone_type_model` (`phone_type_model`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=27 ;

INSERT INTO `phone_types` (`phone_type_id`, `phone_type_manufacturer`, `phone_type_model`) VALUES
(1, 'Polycom', 'SoundPoint IP 550'),
(2, 'Polycom', 'SoundPoint IP 450'),
(3, 'Polycom', 'SoundPoint IP 335'),
(4, 'Polycom', 'SoundPoint IP 560'),
(5, 'Polycom', 'SoundPoint IP 670'),
(6, 'Polycom', 'SoundStation IP 5000'),
(7, 'Polycom', 'SoundStation IP 6000'),
(8, 'Yealink', 'W52P'),
(20, 'Aastra', '6757i CT');
```

I am able to select all the phones from the phone_types table and then get a total count of how many of those phones are within the Phones table, phone_type_id column.

I need to count how many of those phones have a value (NOT NULL) in the Phones table, in did_id or virtual_extension_id. This is where I'm hung up.

Here's what I have so far. Note that I currently am using the same count total and used as I can't figure out the used count. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT 
phone_types.phone_type_id AS phone_type_id, 
phone_type_manufacturer AS phone_type_manufacturer, 
phone_type_model AS phone_type_model, 
COUNT( phones.phone_type_id ) AS total_count, 
COUNT( phones.phone_type_id ) AS used_count
FROM  phone_types 
LEFT JOIN phones ON phones.phone_type_id = phone_types.phone_type_id
GROUP BY phone_types.phone_type_id
```

Sample Output:

```
    1 | Polycom | SoundPoint IP 550    | 2 | 2
    2 | Polycom | SoundPoint IP 450    | 0 | 0
    3 | Polycom | SoundPoint IP 335    | 0 | 0
    4 | Polycom | SoundPoint IP 560    | 0 | 0
    5 | Polycom | SoundPoint IP 670    | 0 | 0
    6 | Polycom | SoundStation IP 5000 | 0 | 0
    7 | Polycom | SoundStation IP 6000 | 0 | 0
    8 | Yealink | W52P                 | 0 | 0
   20 | Aastra  | 6757i CT             | 1 | 1
```

Edited: added create and insert statements.

Edited: Seem to be making progress.

SELECT phone_types.phone_type_manufacturer, phone_types.phone_type_model, COUNT( phones.phone_type_id ) AS Total, COUNT( phones.did_id
OR virtual_extension_id ) AS Used
FROM  `phones` 
INNER JOIN phone_types ON phones.phone_type_id = phone_types.phone_type_id
GROUP BY phones.phone_type_id

which gives me the following output:
manufacturer  model              total  Used
Polycom       Soundpoint IP 550  2      1
Polycom       SoundPoint IP 450  1      0
Aastra        6757i CT           2      1

This is correct but I need to show the other phones also that have a NULL value in both did_id and virtual_extension_id?

Comment: Please reedit you question.

Comment: in order to link the sample data there to be a 20 in phone_types ( for the reference to link ). if the last record is in fact not 9 but (20,'Aastra','6757i CT') then you get exactly the sample output desired..

Comment: ok, so maybe the sample output is what you currently get and you want something else - if so post the desired output

Comment: BTW in `JOIN`s when you're using a common field you can just use `USING (phone_type_id)` instead of `ON ...`.

Comment: My desired output per my initial post in addition to what I've already posted is to somehow reference or query the phones table, checking the did_id and virtual_extension_id columns for any value that is NOT NULL.

Comment: So if you look at my select statement, the second and third count's I need to populate the used count and remaining count. I think I can calculate the remaining so it's really just the used count. That value is based upon whether or not the phone table has a value in the did_id or virtual_extension_id. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: then i think what your looking for is `COUNT( phones.virtual_extension_id is null or phones.did_id is null ) AS used_count`

Comment: Why not provide proper DDLs; you so nearly did

Comment: @amdixon, thank you for your suggestion but that count need to account for the phone_type_id from the phones table also. So if the phone_type_id = 2 (which is a Polycom SoundPoint IP 450) and contains a value either in the did_id or virtual_extension_id, then count...

Comment: @Strawberry, I'm not sure what you are asking for?

Comment: CREATE and INSERT statements, so we can play along

Comment: @Strawberry per your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're after something like this... although I don't really understand how your data set tallies with your result set ?!?!

```
SELECT t.phone_type_id
     , t.phone_type_manufacturer
     , t.phone_type_model
     , COUNT(COALESCE(did_id,virtual_extension_id)) x
  FROM phone_types t 
  LEFT 
  JOIN phones p 
    ON p.phone_type_id = t.phone_type_id
 GROUP 
    BY t.phone_type_id;
```

Comment: thank you! I got it. Added a little to what you just gave me but it works. SELECT t.phone_type_id, t.phone_type_manufacturer, t.phone_type_model, COUNT( p.phone_type_id ) AS Total, COUNT( COALESCE( did_id, virtual_extension_id ) ) Used
FROM phone_types t
LEFT 
JOIN phones p ON p.phone_type_id = t.phone_type_id
GROUP 
BY t.phone_type_id